# playing HLS on Android (compare alternatives)

Tags: android, vitamio, kaltura, http-live-streaming

I want to discuss about HLS in android and want to learn prices , how to buy them, and your experiences for these players.

Vitamio - http://www.vitamio.org/en/

Standart licence is free but it doesn't support adaptive streaming. Is there anyone tested advanced edition or how can i buy advanced version

NexStreaming - http://www.nexstreaming.com/
I sent a mail but no response. Is there anyone tested it ?

Kaltura - http://www.kaltura.org/
It looks like an open source alternative but example code didn't worked for me

Is there any other alternavies ? And what is your experiences for playing HLS on Android..

Thanks..

Comment: Hi @dracula Gstreamer in another alternative..You can check it out at http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorials.But i had issues deploying it in ics and gingerbread.Works well in JellyBean.Have you found any other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Uplynk.com has one, but you have to use their streaming service.  I tried it on a handful of Gingerbread devices with success.  One of my older Gingerbread models has a black frame show up when it switches resolutions, but it works for the most part.

Comment: As of 03 March of 2014 Uplynk.com isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

Use ExoPlayer - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer plays HLS and DASH Live/VOD